# Trying to login from the front end react native, getting error: email is not defined

Tags: react-native

```
 const onSubmitHandler = (values) => fetch('http://07c6717b859b.ngrok.io/user/studentlogin',{
   method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
       
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email:email,
            password:password,
        })
        }).then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

        
return(
   <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: '', password :''}}
     onSubmit={values => onSubmitHandler(values)}
   >
     {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
       <View>
         <TextInput
         icon='email'
         placeholder='email'
           onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
           onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
           value={values.email}
         />
         <TextInput
         icon='password'
         placeholder='password'
           onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
           onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
           value={values.password}
         />
         <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
       </View>
     )}
   </Formik>
 );
     }
     export default Login;
```

I am trying to login from the front end in a React Native app. How can I locate the error?

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting values as a parameter in `onSubmitHandler`. So your email and password will be available as `values.email` and `values.password`. Try this.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  email: values.email,
  password: values.password
});
```